# 3-D surface chart showing the 30 variables with 10000 data points

Tags: python, 3d, data-visualization, tableau-api

I have 30 files, each having 10000 data points related to its 30 variables. I am expected to generate a plot like the attachment. Has anyone tried this before[image]

Answer (score 0):

im not sure how you are planning on plotting 30 variables in 3D space. But `matplotlib` is a python library that has a wide range of plotting tools. you can install it using `pip install matplotlib`